# Moving Laravel installation from subfolder to subdomain without breaking subfolder URL

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, apache2

We had one application which was created in angular and Laravel. So in our production env we put angular app at the root and laravel app in a subfolder within the angular app.

so `/var/www/html` contained the angular app and `/var/www/html/api` contained the complete laravel project.

And used to access our api url something like this.

```
https://example.com/api/public/api/v1/helloworld
```

But now we want to move our api to subdomain for many reasons. so this will be accessible like this.

```
https://api.example.com/api/v1/helloworld
```

This part is easy we did that. but for legacy support reason, we don't to break the old URL's.

is there a way to forward all the request coming to subfolder to the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link in the `public/api/v1/helloworld` folder and map it to the folder where your API app files are hosted.
Also, in your .htaccess file enable `+FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 0):

Just create two virtual hosts. One for your Angular application and second for your Laravel.

Angular virtual host should have `/var/www/html` as document root and `example.com` as domain.
Laravel virtual host should have `/var/www/html/api/public` as document root and `api.example.com` as domain.